# Seeding user doesn't allow user to login in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API - endpoints do allow them to sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity, .net-8.0

When I seed my users into the database at first migration time, I cannot log in at all via the new ASP.NET Core 8 API Identity endpoints.

However, if I create the same user using the new endpoint /register Swagger API and then log in, it works after confirming the user's email and so forth.

But if I merely set `[EmailConfirmed]` to True via SQL in my seed script, it's not working and not allowing my user in. I replaced my real domain with 'testdomain' for security.

```
private void SeedUsers(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Seeding a  'Administrator' role to AspNetRoles table
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
        { Id = "2c5e174e-3b0e-446f-86af-483d56fd7210", 
          Name = "Administrator", 
          NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR".ToUpper() });
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
        { Id = "8cc980c3-8643-4166-8dcb-de924036ec6b", 
          Name = "Staff",
          NormalizedName = "Staff".ToUpper() });

    // a hasher to hash the password before seeding the user to the db
    var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();

    // Seeding the Admin user to AspNetUsers table
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(
      new IdentityUser
      {
          Id = "8e445865-a24d-4543-a6c6-9443d048cdb9", // primary 
          UserName = "testadmin@testdomain.com",
          Email = "testadmin@testdomain.com",
          NormalizedEmail = "TESTADMIN@TESTDOMAIN.COM",
          NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
          LockoutEnabled = false,
          EmailConfirmed = true,
          PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "Test12345!@")
       }
    );

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(
        new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = "2c5e174e-3b0e-446f-86af-483d56fd7210",
                UserId = "8e445865-a24d-4543-a6c6-9443d048cdb9"
            });

    // Seeding the relation staff Member between our user and role to AspNetUserRoles table

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(
         new IdentityUser
             {
                 Id = "d18e858a-c38d-4083-99b6-c5697b81d7cd", // primary 
                 UserName = "Staff",
                 Email = "Staff@testdomain.COM",
                 NormalizedEmail = "STAFF@TESTDOMAIN.COM",
                 NormalizedUserName = "STAFF"
                 EmailConfirmed = true,
                 PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "Test12345!@")
             });

      modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(
      new IdentityUserRole<string>
      {
          RoleId = "8cc980c3-8643-4166-8dcb-de924036ec6b",
          UserId = "d18e858a-c38d-4083-99b6-c5697b81d7cd"
      }
  );
}
```

But if I register my user through here and click the physically click here to activate in email it works

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me what am doing wrong in my seeding?

Answer (score 0):

So the fix was an error in the casing of some the login credentials. But also I had not been populating the securitystamp similar ro this post.

Even though the seed entered a value their physical adding it to seed code seemed to fix issues

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10689

I set it to a guid at time of seeding